# Type inference in repository methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a RepositoryBase class where I define basic crud methods for my Entity Framework Context. I have these two overloads of the All() method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> All<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return All().Where(predicate);
}

public virtual PagedResult<T> All<TKey>(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderingKey, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
    bool sortDescending = false)
{
    var subset =  All().Where(predicate);

    IEnumerable<T> result = sortDescending
                                ? subset.OrderByDescending(orderingKey).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows)
                                : subset.OrderBy(orderingKey).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);

    //More code ommited
}
```

The first method always needs me to explicitly specify the entity type, but the second doesn't. Why is this?

Example, this doesn't compile:

```
return All(s => s.LoanApplicationId == loanApplicationId)
```

And instead I must call it like this:

```
return All<LoanApplication>(s => s.LoanApplicationId == loanApplicationId)
```

But this DOES compile:

```
return All(0,10, s => s.Name, s => s.LoanApplicationId == loanApplicationId, false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TKey` is in the parameter list of the second (via `Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderingKey`) and not the first. That supplies enough for the second to successfully infer the type when you use it with your supplied arguments (`s => s.Name`). You don't give yourself that luxury in the first version, so the compiler forces you to fill in the details by supplying the type parameter explicitly.

And from the looks of it, you don't need `TKey` in the first anyway, so possibly get rid of it (unless there is more code visible than that relatively simple implementation). And I don't think it means what your sample invocation thinks it means. `TKey` in the second is likely `string` (whatever the type of `s.Name` is), for example.